# extending @Html.DropDownList mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, extension-methods, html-helper

In my continuing effort to build out my form validation controls, I've gotten to the dropdownlist control and ran into a snag when I tried to customize this one.

I've tried using the TagBuilder and a simple String in extension methods to extend this control but when I try to "bind" it to a list on the back end, it's not actually binding any data to my dropdownlist.  I'm sure I'm missing something (IEnumerable or the like) on my custom control but I have no idea what....any suggestions (code samples would be terrific) would be awesome.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through the [ASP.NET MVC](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC&referringTitle=Home) source and get an idea as to how it is implemented.

Go through the [License](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/license) as well!!

Comment: that was only sort of helpful.  I'm still having a hard time binding a List to my newly made html helper from my control using @ViewBag.myddl = myList;  I figured since MVC used reflection it'd be able to add this "after the fact" but it's not...any ideas?

Comment: @Christopher Can you post what you have tried so far(by editing the OP)?